# Securepoint client will not launch in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, windows-8.1

An OpenVPN hosted on a CentOS 7 server needs to have a Windows 8.1 client.  But when I install the SecurePoint VPN client and try to launch it, nothing happens.

Specifically, I right click on the desktop icon as shown in the screen shot below, and I choose `Run As Administrator`, and then I click `Yes` to confirm on the resulting dialog box:

[image]

But then nothing happens.  I also get no response when I try it again multiple times, and when I double click on the desktop icon without choosing the Administrator option, and when I similarly right click on the actual application file in Windows File Explorer and try to `Run as Administrator`, as shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

**What else can I do to get the Securepoint VPN client to launch on my Windows 8 Machine?**

And how can I further diagnose the problem?

Comment: Once you've run it, you'll get a small padlock in the taskbar notifications.  Double-click on this to open the application and then choose the cog/wheel icon at the bottom-right to configure it.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thank you.  I am now able to launch Securepoint.  If you want to write this up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.  On my machine, the padlock icon was "hidden" in the extra icons that the user has to click the carrot/arrow on the taskbar to see.  Here is a screen shot of what I actually had to find and click: https://s31.postimg.org/6rtjdngtn/securepoint_taskbar.jpg